# Can I switch the convention of QCD by replacing coupling constant $g$ with $-g$?

Tags: gauge-theory, conventions, quantum-chromodynamics, complex-numbers, yang-mills

There are two equivalent conventions in QCD that give two different definitions of the covariant derivative operator: ${D_\mu } = {\partial _\mu } - {\rm{i}}gA_\mu ^\alpha {T_\alpha }$ and ${D_\mu } = {\partial _\mu } + {\rm{i}}gA_\mu ^\alpha {T_\alpha }$.

And my question is can I switch the conventions of a book simply by replacing all the coupling constant $g$ with $-g$ in its formulas?

I see the value of coupling constant $g$ is always positive in both conventions, does that mean the sign of coupling constant $g$ will not affect on observable quantities?

Comment: You can interpret it as a result of complex conjugation. Redefining $\sqrt{-1}=-i$ definitely does not change anything in the observable world.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful comment. And I'm also wondering if I can switch the conventions of a book by replacing all the coupling constant g with −g in its formulas. Because sometimes I need to rip off some formulas from books in different conventions. @John

Answer (score 1):

Well in SM you compute observable using the squared module of the amplitudes. The sign in front of the coupling enter in the amplitude with the Feynman rules of the vertix so if it doesn't matter when you compute the module. It's the same if you i or -i into the Feynman rule

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And I'm wondering if I can switch the conventions of a book by replacing all the coupling constant g with −g in its formulas. Because sometimes I need to rip off some formulas from books in different conventions.

Comment: Well, I think you can